React native on Windows 11 Downloading templateerror Installing pods failed
Node: 22.5.0
Npm: 10.8.2
react-native: 13.6.9
I try to init demo project with following command:
npx react-native init AwesomeTSProject --template react-native-template-typescript

I get error: "Downloading templateerror Installing pods failed"

And some project npm install run endless. On Ubuntu 24.04 and Windows 10 machine everithing works fine. What can I do on Windows 11?
